# How to search and bookmark multiple strings at once in emeditor?

Tags: emeditor

I want to search and bookmark multiple string at a same time because it will save a lot of my time.

I have a huge text file of 12gb it has 214M lines. I wish to search and bookmark the lines which contains any one of the following;

```
gmail
yahoo
aol
hotmail
comcast
```

Its taking huge time to search and bookmark each one of them I was wondering if there was a way to do it in a single go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Batch Find** feature of **EmEditor**. To do this:

1. In **EmEditor**, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the **Find** dialog box.
2. Click the **Batch >>** button if the dialog box has not been extended already.
3. Copy all the text you want to search for, separated by a newline, (In your sample, copy all 5 lines, between `gmail` and `comcast`) to the Clipboard.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> after you click the Batch list on the right side of the **Find** dialog box.
5. If necessary, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, right-click on the list, and select **Match Case** or **Match Whole Word**.
6. Click the "Batch Bookmark" button.
   [image: EmEditor - Batch Find]

Comment: There is no "Batch>>" button. Is this a new update?
I just checked my version is 19.8.6

Comment: Updated to the latest version and its working now.

Comment: thank you. i thought the save to batch here is the batch processing in windows. it's so convenient